# iWebKit/iPhone: Chatbox with MySQL, AJAX, PHP and Javascript

Tags: mysql, ajax, chat, iphone

i am busy with a chatbox that contains MySQL, AJAX, PHP and Javascript.

Now i want to have this on my iPod Touch/iPhone, so i am building a website with iWebKit.
The following codes i provided is done now; just asking why it does not display the chatbox itself (so not the senders) after more than 2 lines are entered... What codes should i add or remove... Thanks.

I guess something with CSS or so, but i am not sure where i should apply it and what... Or maybe something else?

[Download .zip here with all files](http://www.gdscei.com/chatboxiphone.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Your zip file is all php. I for one won't run someone else's php code on any of my servers. It would be much safer if you gave us a link to the problem page on your server.

Also, you have included the compressed CSS and not included the necessary Javascript file, so anyone wanting to help you would be facing a serious challenge.

Since it might well be an iWebKit issue, try the [iWebKit forum](http://community.iwebkit.net/index.php). They are very helpful there.

Comment: I am really sorry to tell you, but you are not helpfull.

1: If i would give you a link to the problem page, you wouldn't be able to check it;
2: There is no intern Javascript file. It is only using jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, you said you were using iWebKit. So, I assumed the iWebKit js file would be required.

Comment: i already knew that, but the js file including does not help in any way.

Comment: the js file is not designed to do this stuff